# ExtJS 5 - Customize Icon for selectedItem in a ComboBox

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a combobox that is by default having some selection which is highlighted in ExtJS framework. Along with that i also would like to add a smiley gif image for the selected item. Tried changing the style for the "x-boundlist-item" and "x-boundlist-item-selected" classes but nothing seems to be working in make case.

```
Ext.define('App.form.combobox.CutomComboBox', {
    extend         : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias          : 'widget.cutomcombobox', 
    displayField   : 'enumValue',
    valueField     : 'enumCode',
    listConfig     : {
        getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {
                return '<div><img src="images/smiley.gif"> {enumValue}</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`itemTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-itemTpl) property, like:

```
listConfig: {
    itemTpl: '<div class="smile">{enumValue}</div>'
}
```

And use some css like:

```
.x-boundlist-item-selected .smile:before {
  content: "";
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('images/smiley.gif');
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i required, thanks a lot :) I just done small changes in the CSS, instead of "x-boundlist-item-selected" used "x-boundlist-selected" & "background-image" property used "content" which did the trick!